# Actionlink doesn't post the id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my view I have the following actionlink:

```
Html.ActionLink(item.users.nickname, "Details", new { controller = "Account" }, new { id = item.users.id })
```

This should link to Acount/Details/2 but for some reason it only links to Account/Details
I've even tried changing

```
 new { id = item.users.id }
```

into

`new { id = 2 }`

But that gives me the same outcome. I have the default MVC route in place but that shouldn't give any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Html.ActionLink(item.users.nickname, "Details", new { controller = "Account" , id = item.users.id })
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.users.id })` should do it. Where do you determine the text of your link here?